# Discord bot gives "Invalid interaction application command" with WokCommands

Tags: node.js, discord.js, ytdl

I'm trying to create a music bot with WokCommands, Discord.JS & ytdl-core.

Sometimes when i try to run a command all i get is "Invalid interaction application command".
When i wait 10-15minutes with the bot logged in it starts working. The first days of programming the commands worked right away but yesterday they started with this weird behavior. It is not a single command,  its all of them.

Here is play command file:

```
//Dependencies Import
const {
    MessageEmbed
} = require("discord.js");
const voice = require("../voice.js");

module.exports = {
    slash: "both",
    testOnly: false,
    description: "Play audio from youtube URL - Velody",
    minArgs: 1,
    expectedArgs: "<song>",
    callback: async ({
        interaction,
        client,
        args
    }) => {
        let embed = new MessageEmbed();
        embed.setAuthor('Velody', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/linusromland/Velody/master/Velody-logos.jpeg', 'https://github.com/linusromland/Velody')
        embed = voice.play(embed, client, interaction, args[0]);
        return embed;
    },
};
```

I am using Discord.JS 12 & Wokcommands 1.3.6

Comment: It takes time for your slash commands to register make , and since you're using a third party dependency such as WOK commands it may take even more time.

Comment: Deploy your commands to only your guild when testing. This way you don't have to keep waiting to test